# Enforce all keys in a struct

Tags: struct, elixir

How could I enforce all keys in a struct without need to duplicate all the keys? To clarify, I'd like to DRY this:

```
defmodule Ticket do
  @enforce_keys [:origin, :destination, :price]
  defstruct [:origin, :destination, :price]
end
```

I can use additional variable:

```
defmodule Ticket do
  struct_keys = [:origin, :destination, :price]
  @enforce_keys struct_keys
  defstruct struct_keys
end
```

It works properly, but looks noisy. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can pass `@enforce_keys` to `defstruct` since `@enforce_keys` is just a normal module attribute:

```
defmodule Ticket do
  @enforce_keys [:origin, :destination, :price]
  defstruct @enforce_keys
end
```

```
iex(1)> defmodule Ticket do
...(1)>   @enforce_keys [:origin, :destination, :price]
...(1)>   defstruct @enforce_keys
...(1)> end
iex(2)> %Ticket{}
** (ArgumentError) the following keys must also be given when building struct Ticket: [:origin, :destination, :price]
    expanding struct: Ticket.__struct__/1
    iex:2: (file)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!